# change date format date fns, mui datepicker

Tags: material-ui, date-fns

I'm using mui datepicker and it returns something like this
[image]

i need to get it as "DD/MM/YYYY" just to calculate the age later
any ideas how can i change it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are using the date-fns JavaScript date library with the datepicker. This means you are using the datefns Adapter in `<LocalizationProvider>`. If this is the case your datepicker's `onChange` callback function would receive a date object. In your callback you can format this date object using the date-fns `format` function:

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns';

function onChangeCallback( dateObject ) {
  let formattedDateString = format( dateObject, "dd/MM/yyyy"); // date format is case sensitive!
  ...
}
```

You can look up the [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/) for doing calculations on dates for your age calculations.

## UPDATE

Here is a [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kofeigen/Lxp5ykqs/). Click *Run* to start the demo. The code in the demo is compiled, but is displayed below. The JavaScript file is compiled with the file name **index.js** and located in the same directory as **index.html**.

The [date-fns documentation](https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/format) says:

> Please note that the format tokens differ from Moment.js and other libraries.

So, the format as written in your question (i.e. *DD/MM/YYYY*) should be **dd/MM/yyyy**.

### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Material-UI DatePicker Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="testContainer" class="testContainer"></div>
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
        <noscript> Please enable javascript to view the site </noscript>
    </body>

</html>
```

### index.jsx

```js
// index.jsx

import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const container = document.getElementById( 'testContainer' );

import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { StaticDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/StaticDatePicker';
import { format, parse } from 'date-fns';

const dateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
const today = format( new Date(), dateFormat );
const referenceDate = new Date( 1970, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 );

export default function DatePickerComponent() {
    const [ value, setValue ] = React.useState( today );

    /**
     * The 'referenceDate' argument is used to provide values for date parts that are not provided
     * by the 'value' argument. referenceDate will substitute zero for hours, minutes and seconds.
     * @see https://date-fns.org/v2.29.1/docs/parse
     */
     const datefnsDate = parse( value, dateFormat, referenceDate );

    function onChangeCallback( dateObject ) {

        // date format is case sensitive!
        let formattedDateString = format( dateObject, dateFormat );
        setValue( formattedDateString );
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={ AdapterDateFns }>
                <StaticDatePicker
                    open={ open }
                    value={ datefnsDate }
                    openTo={ 'day' }
                    views={ [ 'year', 'month', 'day' ] }
                    allowSameDateSelection={ true }
                    displayStaticWrapperAs={ 'desktop' }
                    disableCloseOnSelect={ true }
                    disableOpenPicker={ true }
                    onChange={ onChangeCallback }
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>

            { /* Display selected date */ }
            <div>
                { 'Selected date: ' + value }
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}


/**
 * Inject component into DOM
 */
ReactDOM.render(
    <DatePickerComponent />,
    container
);
```

Comment: i'll assume that i don't know how to use that since it said invalid date format any chance you have an example that i could see ?

Comment: @Ryuga My answer was updated with a jsFiddle demo and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just using this inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={ AdapterDateFns }>
            <StaticDatePicker
                open={ open }
                value={ datefnsDate }
                openTo={ 'day' }
                inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                allowSameDateSelection={ true }
                displayStaticWrapperAs={ 'desktop' }
                disableCloseOnSelect={ true }
                disableOpenPicker={ true }
                onChange={ onChangeCallback }
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>

        { /* Display selected date */ }
        <div>
            { 'Selected date: ' + value }
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
);
```

}